# Is the time complexity of push and pop of priority queue and insertion and deletion of max_heap same?

Tags: c++, time-complexity, heap, priority-queue

I am confused about time complexity of push pop of priority queue and insertion deletion of max_heap.Do they take same time when the input is very long like 10^5 ??which one will be faster priority queue or max_heap??I am trying to solve a problem where input is very long.But  when I use heap I get runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

`priority_queue` is implemented in terms of a heap, it's just providing the interface that guarantees the heap invariant is maintained (unlike using a plain `vector` + `make_heap`, where it's initially a heap, but the developer can break the invariant by misusing the `vector` directly afterwards).

If you're having troubles with the result of `make_heap` that you don't have with `priority_queue`, it's probably because your code for manipulating the heap is incorrect; they should both work equally well (`priority_queue` just simplifies things for you a bit). Without a reproducer, I can't say what you did wrong.

Comment: so their time complexities are same.?but priority_queue is easier to implement

Comment: @sunflower: Using `make_heap` gives you more control (you can inspect the heap structure directly, since it's just a plain sequence like an array or `vector`, or push on a bunch of items and rerun `make_heap` at `O(n)` cost instead of `O(log n)` per push, where `priority_queue` can only benefit from that on construction, not for later bulk pushes), but if you don't need that fine-grained control, just go with the `priority_queue`.